# How do I obfuscate Javascript in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, obfuscation

Does anyone know how to use the  [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator) (or similar) in Ember ?

I guess it needs to be called inside **ember-cli-build.js** but I don't know where and how.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a really straightforward answer to this. If you're running on [embroider](https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider), then all your Javascript will be handled by `webpack`, so you could try using [webpack-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator) -- in your `ember-cli-build.js` something like

```js
return require('@embroider/compat').compatBuild(app, Webpack, {
  plugins: [
    new WebpackObfuscator(/*whatever args*/)
  ],
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      enforce: 'post',
      use: { 
        loader: WebpackObfuscator.loader, 
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

The other options I know of would be to write a broccoli plugin. What you're doing is analogous to what `ember-cli-terser` does -- post-process Javascript files before they get concatenated together -- so you could use that as reference.

You would need to write a broccoli plugin that actually performs the transformations (the analog is [broccoli-terser-sourcemap](https://github.com/ember-cli/broccoli-terser-sourcemap)) and an Ember addon to hook it into `ember-cli`'s build pipeline (the analog is [ember-cli-terser](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-terser)).

### Broccoli plugin

Looking at `broccoli-terser-sourcemap`'s `index.js`, which is only 114 lines of code, I would think you could adapt it to something like this:

```js
module.exports = class TerserWriter extends Plugin {
  constructor(_inputNodes, options = {}) {
    let inputNodes = Array.isArray(_inputNodes) ? _inputNodes : [_inputNodes];

    super(inputNodes, {
      name: options.name,
      annotation: options.annotation,
      needsCache: false,
    });

    this.options = defaults(options, {
      obfuscator: {},
    });

    let exclude = this.options.exclude;
    if (Array.isArray(exclude)) {
      this.excludes = new MatcherCollection(exclude);
    } else {
      this.excludes = MatchNothing;
    }
  }

  async build() {
    let pendingWork = [];

    this.inputPaths.forEach(inputPath => {
      walkSync(inputPath).forEach(relativePath => {
        if (relativePath.slice(-1) === '/') {
          return;
        }
        let inFile = path.join(inputPath, relativePath);
        let outFile = path.join(this.outputPath, relativePath);

        fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(outFile), { recursive: true });

        if (this._isJSExt(relativePath) && !this.excludes.match(relativePath)) {
          pendingWork.push(() => this.processFile(inFile, outFile, relativePath, this.outputPath));
        } else {
          symlinkOrCopy.sync(inFile, outFile);
        }
      });
    });

    for (let fn of pendingWork) {
      await fn();
    }
  }

  _isJSExt(relativePath) {
    return relativePath.slice(-3) === '.js' || relativePath.slice(-4) === '.mjs';
  }

  async processFile(inFile, outFile, relativePath, outDir) {
    let input = await readFile(inFile).toString();
    let result = obfuscate(input, this.options.obfuscator);
    await writeFile(outFile, result.getObfuscatedCode());
  }
};
```

You could also do the worker pooling this that `broccoli-terser-sourcemaps` does, and if you care about source maps you'd need to handle them as well, but `broccoli-terser-sourcemaps` does just that, so you could use it as reference.

#### `ember-cli` addon

`ember-cli-terser` has even less code -- looking at its `index.js`, you could adapt it to something like

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  name: require('./package').name,

  included(app) {
    this._super.included.apply(this, arguments);

    let defaultOptions = {
      enabled: app.env === 'production',

      obfuscator: {
        // default `javascript-obfuscator` options
      },
    };

    let addonOptions = app.options['ember-cli-obfuscator'];

    this._obfuscatorOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, addonOptions);
  },

  postprocessTree(type, tree) {
    if (this._obfuscatorOptions.enabled === true && type === 'all') {
      // Import the plugin code above
      const Obfuscator = require('./broccoli-obfuscator');

      return new Obfuscator(tree, this._obfuscatorOptions);
    } else {
      return tree;
    }
  }
};
```

Then you'd have to install the above addon in your app (it could be an in-repo addon), and it should do its thing!

This would definitely take some doing, but what you're doing is so similar to what `ember-cli-terser` is doing, just using the `obfuscator` API instead of the `terser` API, that you have a really good starting point.

BUT, if `embroider` is an option for you, I'd definitely try that route first because it might just be a matter of configuration, rather than writing a bunch of code.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!